# Set HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase.Browser for Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-edge

I have a method that's used to return a string based on the browser. However it's basing the browser on one of it's parameters, `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase`, which has a property called `Browser` and for Edge it's being set to "*Chrome*".

(I've simplified the code.)

```
public static string GetStringBasedOnBrowser(System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase browser)
{
    string returnString;

    if (browser.Browser == "IE" && (browser.MajorVersion <= 8))
        returnString = "something";
    else if (browser.Browser == "Edge")
        returnString = "something else"; // Never reached.
    else
        returnString = "42";

    return returnString;
}
```

I wanted to send a fake `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` to avoid messing with the functionality but it only has a getter. `HttpBrowserCapabilities` inherits from it but there's nothing I can set in the constructor to get Browser set to "*Edge*".

Is there a way I can fake this?

Comment: Use the Request.UserAgent, for MS Edge, you will see something like this:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4435.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.825.0"
Then you can pass a HttpRequestBase to the GetStringBasedOnBrowser method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET browsers capabilities information is based on a list of agent strings that is massively out of date and isn't being maintained.<sup>1</sup> The database was last updated before Edge existed.

There are two options:

- A third party browser database. These cost money.
- Don't do it. Better to handle only the largest browser differences (eg. desktop vs. mobile) on rendering the HTML. The detailed differences should be handled on the client, ideally in CSS but usually some JavaScript is required where particularly obsolete browsers have to be handled.

<sup>1</sup> The product release cycles for ASP.NET are just too slow to handle the diversity and rate of change of browsers of over 5 years ago,<sup>2</sup> it has only got worse.

<sup>2</sup> It is at least that long ago, it could be several years before that.